# How to migrate an attribute on an entity to an entity in Core Data

Tags: ios, core-data, core-data-migration

I'm struggling with quite a complex Core Data mapping issue which I can't seem to get my head around. Basically, I have a version of a managed object with an attribute which is a string. This string is the same across many objects. As it's the same, I thought it would make sense to change it so that it is a single entity, with an attribute 'name'.

entity.attribute should become entity.newObject.name, where both attribute and name are strings.

To complicate matters, I want the attribute, currently split across many entities, to become a single instance of an entity. In addition, the new entity should have a one-to-many relationship back to the objects which had attributes matching newObject.name.

Is there any way I can do this through mapping models in Core Data? I understand that automatic migration is out of the question.

I want to go from this:

[Diagram of current model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQh3y.png)

to this:

[Diagram of wanted model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DyV81.png)

I'm doing this to speed up fetch requests for times matching a particular puzzle type in a particular session. The thinking is that -[NSSet intersectSet] would be much quicker than comparing each individual time's puzzleType attribute to a string. How would I go about doing this, either through a mapping model or programmatically?

Answer (score 1):

You can use automatic migration, you just can't infer the mapping automatically.

The high level tasks will be:

1. Create a new model version.
2. Configure the new model however you'd like.
3. Set the new model version as the current version.
4. Create a mapping model from the old version to the new version, where you will set what  $source.attributes map to what new attributes.
5. Set the NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption option to NO when you configure the persistent store coordinator.
6. Leave the NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption option as YES. You only set this to NO when you want to use a migration manager to show migration progress.

Let me know if you need deeper instruction on any of those items.